# Pandas DataFrame returning a Tuple, but cannot access individual numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

I have a very simple DataFrame

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NF328.png)

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel('HSH_Data.xlsx')

config = 'A1A2-Car-SiC'
seal_size = 2125

p1 = (data.loc[(data.Configuration == config) & (data.Seal == seal_size), 'D1']), \
     (data.loc[(data.Configuration == config) & (data.Seal == seal_size), 'D2'])

print(p1)
```

this return the following:

```
(12    4.375
Name: D2, dtype: float64, 12    4.063
Name: L2, dtype: float64)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I would like to access 4.063 and 0.566 individually, anyone can support?
if I use

```
print(p1[0][1])
```

I get so many errors

Comment: try printing `p1[0]`...

Comment: where is `0.566`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just look at `p1.D2.values[0]` or `p1.L2.values[0]`.